# Symfony 3 custom repository factory

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, dependency-injection

Создаю контейнер в service.php

`$container->setDefinition('repository.access_token', new Definition(\Ftob\OauthServerApp\Repositories\AccessTokenRepository::class))
    ->setFactory([new Reference('doctrine'), 'getRepository'])
    ->setArguments([\Ftob\OauthServerApp\Entity\AccessToken::class]);`

Пытаюсь вызвать его в тесте -

```
class AccessTokenRepositoryTest extends KernelTestCase
{

protected $repository;

public function setUp()
{
    $this->bootKernel();
    $this->repository = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('repository.access_token');
}

public function testDi()
{

    $this->assertInstanceOf( AccessTokenRepository::class, $this->repository);
}

}
```

Получаю ошибку (fail) -

```
AccessTokenRepositoryTest::testDi
Failed asserting that Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository Object (...) is an    
instance of class "Ftob\OauthServerApp\Repositories\AccessTokenRepository".

/var/www/tests/Repositories/AccessTokenRepositoryTest.php:23
FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

Cобственно, вопрос... Почему вызывается `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`, а не `AccessTokenRepository`?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А в приложении (не в тестах), если спрашиваете `$entityManager->getRepository(\Ftob\OauthServerApp\Entity\AccessToken::class)`, что возвращает?
Скорее всего проблема не в контейнере и не в инструкциях создания службы.

*Doctrine* не видит, `AccessTokenRepository` в качестве *custom repository* для `AccessToken` и возвращает дефолтный `EntityRepository`.

Как и когда Вы указываете *Doctrine* использовать `AccessTokenRepository` как репозиторий для своих сущностей `AccessToken`?

Присутствует ли у Вас что-то подобное в объявлении класса? Объявление:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ftob\OauthServerApp\Repositories\AccessTokenRepository")
*/
class AccessToken
{
    //...
}
```

(*или Вы указываете метаданные в YAML/XML? В целом неважно какой именно формат метаданных Вы выбрали. Важно, чтобы на момент обращения к `EntityManager::getRepository()` они могли быть считанны*).

Если, да, и в рабочем приложении вызов `$entityManager->getRepository(\Ftob\OauthServerApp\Entity\AccessToken::class)` возвращает Ваш кастомный репозиторий, значит это у Вас зависит от особенностей тестового окружения (я, правда, слабо пока что представляю каким образом), тогда смотрите, что у Вас перебивается в тестовой среде. Проверьте через `X-Debug` чем отличается сбор метаданных о классе в приложении и в тестах.

Comment: Добавил 

` $this->assertInstanceOf(AccessTokenRepository::class, $em->getRepository(AccessToken::class));`

Тест проходит, подумал, почистил кеш в redis - все заработало.
Проблема была в тестовом окружение.